# How can i convert a row of database on display into textboxes when a user click edit button corresponding to that row

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

i am newbie in java.i am displaying my database content through a jsp. I want that when a user click edit button corresponding to that row of database being displayed then that row contents should be displayed in textboxes while rest of the rows remains the same.

my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script language="javascript">


function deleteData(id){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/First/deleteData1?id="+id+"&format=fragment",true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    //alert(xmlhttp.status==200);
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}


}

function editData(id){

    var xmlhttp1;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp1 = new ActiveXobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp1.open("GET","",true);
xmlhttp1.send(null);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">
    <form>
    <table border='1' width='300' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=7 align="center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Department</td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>

        <%
            List Li = new ArrayList();
            Iterator lr;

            if (request.getAttribute("userList") != null
                    && request.getAttribute("userList") != "") {
                List userList = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("userList");
                Iterator itr = userList.iterator();

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Li = (ArrayList) itr.next();
                    lr = Li.iterator();
                    Integer id = (Integer) lr.next();
                    String name = (String) lr.next();
                    String department = (String) lr.next();
                    String password = (String) lr.next();
        %>

        <tr>
            <td><%=id%></td>
            <td><%=name%></td>
            <td><%=department%></td>
            <td><%=password%></td>

            <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="edit" onclick="editData(<%=id%>);"></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteData(<%=id%>);"></td>
        </tr>

        <%
            }
            }
        %>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use `flag(boolean)` variable, that if variable is `true` then edit mode start and `textbox show` otherwise when variable is `false` `hide textbox` and `show simple row` and it's quite easy to set data in that textboxes as well as in simple row.

Comment: can you clarify more or post few code segments to make it clear.

Comment: Wait a minute i ll post you. Show your jsp code.

Comment: Here's a link http://pastebin.com/LV230pLr, I have used knockout js, you jst have to replace it with your java code or java script code and then change it's html data to show data.

Comment: can't i do it only through javascript without using knockout.js

Comment: Yes you can, you will have to do stuff in Java Script and that will handle your requests, it's not necessary to use knockout,I have just shown you one simple example.

Comment: Still i couldn't do it.can you please show how can i do it with javascript(without knockout.js).